# bash how to extract a field based on its content from a delimited string

Tags: bash

Problem - I have a set of strings that essentially look like this:

```
|AAAAAA|BBBBBB|CCCCCCC|...|XXXXXXXXX|...|ZZZZZZZZZ|
```

The '...' denotes omitted fields.
Please note that the fields between the pipes ('|') can appear in ANY ORDER and not all fields are necessarily present.  My task is to find the "XXXXXXX" field and extract it from the string; I can specify that field with a regex and find it with grep/awk/etc., but once I have that one line extracted from the file, I am at a loss as to how to extract just that text between the pipes.

My searches have turned up splitting the line into individual fields and then extracting the Nth field, however, I do not know what N is, that is the trick.

I've thought of splitting the string by the delimiter, substituting the delimiter with a newline, piping those lines into a grep for the field, but that involves running another program and this will be run on a production server through near-TB of data, so I wanted to minimize program invocations. And I cannot copy the files to another machine nor do I have the benefit of languages like Python, Perl, etc., I'm stuck with the "standard" UNIX commands on SunOS. I think I'm being punished.

Thanks

Comment: _"I can specify that field with a regex"_  It would be helpful if you showed an example of such a regex.

Comment: Also show sample input data with expected output.

Comment: `grep -o XXXXXXX file`? `grep XXXXXXX file | tr \| '\n' |grep XXXXXXX`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, let's extract the field that matches `MyField`:

#### Using sed

```
$ s='|AAAAAA|BBBBBB|CCCCCCC|...|XXXXXXXXX|12MyField34|ZZZZZZZZZ|'
$ sed -E 's/.*[|]([^|]*MyField[^|]*)[|].*/\1/' <<<"$s"
12MyField34
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F\| -v re="MyField" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~re) print $i}' <<<"$s"
12MyField34
```

#### Using `grep -P`

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=\|)[^|]*MyField[^|]*' <<<"$s"
12MyField34
```

The `-P` option requires GNU grep.

Comment: Thanks for the response. None of the examples work on SunOS, unfortunately, which is a never-ending theme. Since the machine is production, we probably are not going see anything modern. Using that as an excuse, I'm going to run this on my Mac, and the sed example works quite well. The underlying answer is to substitute the entire line with just the part that matches the regex, and so I give myself a great big "Duh!"

Comment: @user3481644 Sorry about that.  On SunOS, the default `awk` does have some bugs.  Try  `nawk` or                                                   
better yet `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`  or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -e 's/^.*|\(XXXXXXXXX\)|.*$/\1/'
```

Naturally, this only makes sense if `XXXXXXXXX` is a regular expression.

This should be really fast if used something like:

```
$ grep '|XXXXXXXXX|' somefile | sed -e ...
```

Answer (score 1):

One hackish way -

```
sed 's/^.*|\(<whatever your regex is>\)|.*$/\1/'
```

but that might be too slow for your production server since it may involve a fair amount of regex backtracking.

Comment: Thanks for the response, which I think is good, but, oddly, no matter what I use for the regex ... "<whatever your regex is>" ... the entire file is output, blank lines and all. I even cut-n-pasted your sed command and got every line in the file. This happens on SunOS and MAC OS X.